# PHP is not called properly in IE using set interval function in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to show the message updated in DB using the following code

```
var showtime = setInterval('redirect()',5000);
////Redirecting to DB Status /////
function redirect()
{   
 xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
 if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
     alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
     return;
    }
    var url="isResultexist.php"
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

I am collecting the response from PHP here and using it to update the Messages on UI
Problem here is it works fine 1st time when it called after 5sec but there after return the Same result even DB is updated,

This works fine with Mozilla and google chrome browser

regards
hemant

Comment: You are missing the important part of your code, namely where you actually change the HTML.

Comment: I can't see where you are using the result from the http request. You will need to provide more code.

Answer (score 4):

the IE is caching the response, so try to set an expires-header in your isResultexist.php, add a random parameter to each request or switch from get to post (post isn't cached).

Comment: Time is always a good one (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php)
or yeah, a random number would work well too.
(http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: i think the best solution is the last one i posted - a "random" parameter will be chached, too, so after some time the cache would be full of trash - and the expires-header is sometimes ignored by this dumb piece of software aka internet explorer